# Next Auth with Google Provider: To confirm your identity, sign in with the same account you used originally

Tags: prisma, next-auth, t3

I'm using T3 Stack and next auth to authenticate with google, currently using mysql DB,

but while trying to logging in I'm getting

`To confirm your identity, sign in with the same account you used originally.`

How can I resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This happens if you already sign-up with one provider (say Github) and then you try to sign-up with another provider (maybe Google this time) that uses same email. NextAuth intentionally does not support auto linking of accounts because of security concerns.

From the official doc: https://next-auth.js.org/faq

> When an email address is associated with an OAuth account it does not
> necessarily mean that it has been verified as belonging to account
> holder — how email address verification is handled is not part of the
> OAuth specification and varies between providers (e.g. some do not
> verify first, some do verify first, others return metadata indicating
> the verification status).
>
> With automatic account linking on sign in, this can be exploited by
> bad actors to hijack accounts by creating an OAuth account associated
> with the email address of another user.

If you want to get rid of this for testing purposes, you can simply remove the related user from the database (DO NOT DO THIS IN PRODUCTION THOUGH!).

### Update:

As @KHB comment below; you may also use `allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking` setting to allow linking between identity providers.

Docs: https://authjs.dev/guides/providers/custom-provider

Comment: You mean to say sign up / sing In on same website with multiple providers?

Comment: @ShubhamNikam yes. If you already sing-up with one, you must keep sign-in with the same.

Comment: Next now supports linking some accounts via e-mail address by placing the following key/value pair in the nextauth config within the Provider's configuration object:
`allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking: true`
documentation here: https://authjs.dev/guides/providers/custom-provider